# How to send a UIlabel value of tableview to another view in IPhone?

Tags: xcode, uitableview

I need to pass the UiLabel value of selected tableviews row to a label in other view .How can I do it?
I tried this:

```
 ViewController1.h:
UILabel *name1;
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *name1;

    ViewController1.m:
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

ViewController2 *v2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
v2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:YES];
 v2.provName=[name1 retain];   //name1 is the name of UILabel in TableView.
[v2 release];
}
    ViewController2.h
UILabel *providerName;
SString *provName;

    ViewController2.m:
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
providerName =[[UILabel alloc] init];
[providerName setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,50) ];
providerName.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
providerName.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

self.providerName.text=self.provName; 
 providerName.highlightedTextColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:providerName];
}
```

But not getting the value

Comment: First `NSLog(@"name1 = %@",name1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `provName` is a string, assign it the value of the label's text instead of the label itself.

Comment: I did this but still no luck  v2.provName=[name1 text];

Comment: Also, move the assignment to `provName` before the line that presents the controller.

Comment: Can u explain briefly.I couldn't get u

Comment: Switch the order of the two lines...first `v2.provName=[name1 text];` then `[self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:YES];` so that the text is available when `viewDidLoad` runs.

Comment: To check what's happening, set a breakpoint on `self.providerName.text=self.provName;` and look at the value of `provName`.

Comment: I have changed like this :v2.provName=[name1 text]; [self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:YES];But the problem is whatever the row I select I am getting the last row's name1 value in UIlabel.How can I do it?If I select 1st row hen the name1 value of that particular row should be passed.If I select 2nd row then name1 value of that particular row should be passed .....

Comment: You will get whatever you have connected to the `name1` variable.  Since it's only one item, of course it can only hold one value.  If you need something from a specific row, use the `indexPath` to get the right cell or array element and choose the "label" data that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should update the text of the label in the second view controller:

```
v2.providerName.text = name1.text;
```

Or, better still, encapsulate the name in the second view controller that you do this in teh first view controller:

```
v2.provName = name1.text;
```

and provide a setter in the second view controller:

```
- (void)setProvName:(NSString *)name
{
    // This assumes that ARC is enable - if it isn't then you have to retain...

    self.provName = name;
    self.providerName.text = name;
}
```